# Constructors precedence

Tags: .net, constructor

I have to build a special class behavior depending of the constructor's argument. Say the Foo drawing should became forever green, if it was build(drawn) with a green pencil.
If any pencil where used, the Foo should be transparent...

Now, look at the code bellow. Is there a possibility to modify the "output" that the constructor "see" the real type of the passed in parameter object? (actually they are all "object"s):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[] objs = { new IndexOutOfRangeException(), MyEnum.Beta, 45, new AssemblyName(), new { Name = "a" } };

        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1} ", i, objs[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("=========================== ");
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            Foo myFoo = new Foo(objs[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", i, myFoo);
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    object value;
    string typeName;

    public Foo(object obj)
    {
        value = obj;
        typeName = "object";
    }

    public Foo(MyEnum enm)
    {
        value = enm;
        typeName = "MyEnum";
    }

    public Foo(int myInt)
    {
        value = myInt;
        typeName = "int";
    }

    public Foo(Exception ex)
    {
        value = ex;
        typeName = "exception";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("FOO (object = '{0}'; type = '{1}')", value, typeName);
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    Alpha,
    Beta
}
```

OUTPUT

```
0 => System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
1 => Beta
2 => 45
3 =>
4 => { Name = a }

===========================

0 => FOO (object = 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bound
s of the array.'; type = 'object')
1 => FOO (object = 'Beta'; type = 'object')
2 => FOO (object = '45'; type = 'object')
3 => FOO (object = ''; type = 'object')
4 => FOO (object = '{ Name = a }'; type = 'object')
```

**EDIT:**

As see some answers, I would like to stress that is not about the correct string to be displayed in the "type" variable, like using `value.GetType()`, but is about "entering" in the correct constructor is the question.

In other words, **Why does the compiler not detect the correct type and "redirects" it to the correct constructor?**

**EDIT 2:**

As mentioned by the answerers, the "way" to constructor is "built" at compile time, not in runtime. say a code like his

```
MyEnum en = MyEnum.Beta;
Console.WriteLine("Enum example: obj:{0} Foo:{1}", en, new Foo(en));
```

Will output the "good" output:

```
Enum example: obj:Beta Foo:FOO (object = 'Beta'; type = 'MyEnum')
```

so... apparently, any way to "bypass" this behavior but the runtime detection in constructor, like proposed Reed Copsey... ?!

Comment: The compiler cannot detect the type because the type is not known until runtime. Therefore it cannot determine the correct cctor.

Comment: @David Neale: Thanks. I need a workaround to "bypass" that. )

Comment: What is wrong with the suggestion of using reflection (`GetType()`) to get the type name? When you get to runtime then that is the only way that you can do this. Otherwise - why are you looping through these objects? Is it necessary?

Comment: @David Neale: because I don't care about the type name, I used "hardcoded" strings express to demonstrate that the constructor is always the same...

Comment: Your edit is flawed, though - the type is known at compile time.  Try changing it to:  `object en = MyEnum.Beta; Console....`, and you'll see you get `type = 'object'` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the compiler not detect the correct type and "redirects" it to the correct constructor?

This is because you're passing in the object as a `System.Object`.  (`object[] objs = { n...`)  The constructor is chosen *at compile time*, not at runtime.  The declaration of the variable used is seen by the compiler, and used to check for the appropriate type.

As you mentioned in another comment:

> ok, what if I have a big array of objects, and don't know, a priori their type?

This is exactly why the compiler works this way.  It can't know, at compile time, which constructor you want, and since you have a `System.Object` constructor which works, it gets chosen.

If you want to handle these specific types separately, but still construct the object as a `System.Object`, you'd have to add checks for that inside of the constructor for object and handle specific cases separately.  This is not the most maintainable code, however, if you do that.

```
public Foo(object obj)
{
    value = obj;
    typeName = "object";

    // Change typeName if appropriate
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if (obj is MyEnum)
           typeName = "MyEnum";
        else if (obj is int)
           typeName = "int";
        else if (obj is Exception)
           typeName = "exception";
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

Given that, in your real code, the constructor is likely going to do a lot more work, I would consider making a factory method to handle this.  It would allow you to use a similar approach as above, but leave the type safe constructors in place:

```
// I'd make the object constructor private, to prevent accidental usage:
private Foo(object obj) { ...

public static Foo CreateAppropriateFoo(object obj)
{
     if (obj == null)
         return new Foo(obj); // Use object constructor
     else
     {            
        if (obj is MyEnum)
           return new Foo( (MyEnum)obj );
        else if (obj is int)
           return new Foo( (int)obj );
        else if (obj is Exception)
           return new Foo( (Exception)obj );
     }
}
```

This, at least, prevents the duplication of the constructor logic, as well as makes it a little more obvious that there is some logic happening at runtime.

Comment: so, you propose me to replace all specific constructors to one large and common... I thought I can avoid it...

Comment: @serhio: I wouldn't necessarily replace them, but if you want to be able to pass an `Object` in and have the type determined, you need to do the check at runtime.  The compiler won't handle this, for the reasons I mentioned above.  Leaving the other constructors is fine, as it allows the compiler to figure this out properly when you pass in an actual type (ie: an exception, declared as Exception or a subclass)

Comment: Yes, but I will duplicate the code in that way. As (incorrectly) proposed Devendra D. Chavan, I can't, unfortunately, use a constructor in an other in order do not duplicate the code...

Comment: @serhio: Well, you could have a single constructor - alternatively, you could have a static factory method that constructs based on the object, and call the appropriate constructor based on the type passed in.  (This is likely my favorite approach, btw..., especially if the constructors are doing more than the trivial work here.)

Comment: or... or... I could eliminate at all the "object" constructor... oh, surely, in the real project my constructors does more that the trivial work that in that sample ... )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you wanted by either remove the ctor which accepts an object parameter (then everything should bind to the proper constructor properly), or by casting a the parameter to proper type, for example this one:

```
var myFoo = new Foo(objs[0] as Exception);
```

will most likely use the ctor with an Exception parameter.

**EDIT:** your question: *Why does the compiler not detect the correct type and "redirects" it to the correct constructor?*

my answer: because you are passing a member of an object array so the compiler is **right** in handling that actual object instance as object.

it's like the catch blocks which must be ordered from most generic to more general going down, you have a generic catcher at the top having your ctor to accept an object and you should not be surprised that passing a value from an object array the compiler uses the most suitable candidate. That's why I suggested you to do a cast on calling the ctor, so that you can esplicitely tell that you want to cast objs[0] to an Exception object, or the compiler will consider it as object.

Comment: ok, what if I have a big array of objects, and don't know, *a priori* their type?